# Do not display alert again after user clicked dismiss(x) or refreshed the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert, dismiss

I am trying to create an alert on website which will not show up again after user clicked dismiss(x). Basically if user clicked X and refreshed the page - the alert should not be displayed anymore. (Similar to cookies policy bar)

Can someone let me know how to do it?

So far I have:

```
<div class="flash flash-warning alert alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <span><strong>Shipping</strong>  Flat and simple rates, check it out <a href="#" style="color: white; text-decoration: underline;">here</a></span>
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';"><strong>&times;</strong></span>
</div>
```

And then CSS

```
.flash {
  padding: 5px 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #2A92E5;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* The close button */
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the close button */
.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with only HTML & CSS

Comment: @alaboudi Yes, this I know :)